# How to construct a JSON with nested lists

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I need to dynamically construct the following JSON.

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "code": "200",
  "output": {
    "studentid": "1001",
    "name": "Kevin"
  }
}
```

I tried it with the *jsonlite* package, but I can't construct the inner JSON object. Please help me try to resolve this.

Comment: I think you can just create a nested list and then use `toJSON`.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the comments, you can create a nested list and use `toJSON()`.

```
library(jsonlite)
x <- list(status = "SUCCESS", code = "200", 
    output = list(studentid = "1001", name = "Kevin"))
toJSON(x, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

which gives the following output:

```
{
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "code": "200",
  "output": {
    "studentid": "1001",
    "name": "Kevin"
  }
}
```